# "--with-x=yes (default) and X11 headers/libs are not available"

Tags: compiling, configure, r

I am trying to install R in our cluster (the cluster is Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6), where I don't have root access. I tried:

```
$wget http://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/R-3.1.1.tar.gz
$ tar xvf R-3.1.1.tar.gz
$ cd R-3.1.1
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/Kryo/R-3.1.1
```

But I am getting an error:

```
configure: error: --with-x=yes (default) and X11 headers/libs are not available
```

Comment: The error message looks pretty clear. Either install X11 development files or use `--without-x`.

Comment: Did you consider asking your sysadmin? Can't you use R on your own Linux workstation or laptop? A supercomputer is generally supposed to crunch numbers in efficient, compiled, code. You could prototype your algorithms on your laptop, then, if you need the power of your supercomputer, rewrite in C++ or Fortran (or even OpenCL) the critical parts of it. HPC are generally not bought to run interpreted code!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch. I am working on analysing next generation sequencing data which needs a huge computational space. Impossible to work in worstation or laptop.

Comment: Then I believe that R is not for this.... Supercomputers are costly enough (w.r.t. to qualified human labor cost) to be programmed in efficient compiled languages (e.g. C++, Fortran, OpenCL, perhaps Ocaml or Go or Common Lisp or Scala....). So use R for prototyping *only* (or for pre- or post- processing, which could run on a desktop), especially if you need huge computational power.

Comment: @jordanm..it worked,

Comment: @jordanm please post answers as answers (or, alternatively, if you think the question should be closed, vote to close).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5933), you should just install `libXt-devel` package and you should be fine.

But perhaps you also should install `xorg-x11-server-devel` and `libX11-devel`?

That would be:

```
yum install xorg-x11-server-devel libX11-devel libXt-devel
```

Comment: Great advice. On the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8, I can't find `xorg-x11-server-devel` using the `sudo yum list xorg-x11-server-devel` command. But using a wildcard search `sudo yum list xorg-x11-*`, I found a similar one named `xorg-x11-drv-evdev-devel`. With that the `./configure` command no longer complains about X11 anymore.

Answer (score -1):

use this command:

```
./configure --without-x
```

Comment: This would disable X altogether. It is not clear that this is what the user in question wants to do.